# Parse an txt file with tags in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, text-files

I have a .txt file that is like this:

```
Title: Test
Author: zad0xsis
Date: July 13th, 2011
Body: This is a test post and this can continue until the file end
```

How could I make PHP to recognize the "tags" and make the content to a new string? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: The 'tag' is the `Something:` at the start of each line?

Comment: yes, and the body tag is the last one

Comment: no, only a word and then a colon, which marks the end of the tag identifier

Comment: I noticed my solution doesn't really work for your multi-line body, so I added a second example.  Again, much of the control and flow and what is done with these things is left as an exercise to you, partially because I don't know your exact application, and partially because you'll learn better by doing than reading (probably) =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
function parse($filename)
{
  $lines = file($filename);
  $content = array();
  foreach ($lines as $line)
  {
    $posColon = strpos($line, ":");
    $tag = substr($line, 0, $posColon);
    $body = substr($line, $posColon+1);

    $content[$tag] = trim($body);
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$fc = file('some_file.txt'); // read file into array
foreach ($fc as $line) {
    list($tag, $content) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    // do something here
}
```

Now, are there multiple unrelated sets in each file?  If so, you'll have to look for some marker, maybe a new line, and do a reset.  Hopefully you can figure this part out on your own.

Some functions for you to check out:

- [`file`](http://php.net/file)
- [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)
- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)
- [`list`](http://php.net/list) (not really a function)

#### Edit: slightly expanding the example:

```
$fc = file('some_file.txt'); // read file into array
foreach ($fc as $index => $line) {
    list($tag, $content) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    // do something here
    if ('body' == strtolower($tag)) {
        $content = join(array_slice($fc, $index + 1, count($fc)));
        break;
    }
}
```

More functions for you!

- [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower)
- [`join` (aka `implode`)](http://php.net/implode)
- [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array-slice)
- [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) - this is not used in my solution, but you may want to use it to trim the newline chars from the end of the lines as returned by `file()`.  Alternatively, you can use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag when calling `file()`, and more information on that can be found in the [PHP Manual entry for `file()`](http://php.net/file) (also linked above).

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! Well I think I understood your question, those .txt files follow all the same layout

Answer (score 3):

Another solution: [demo here](http://www.ideone.com/c9Qrt)

```
<?php

  //$sample = file_get_contents('myfile.txt'); // read from file

  $sample = "Title: Test
Author: zad0xsis
Date: July 13th, 2011
Body: This is a test post and this can continue until the file end";

  $re = '/^(?<tag>\w+):\s?(?<content>.*)$/m';

  $matches = null;
  if (preg_match_all($re, $sample, $matches))
  {
    for ($_ = 0; $_ < count($matches['tag']); $_++)
      printf("TAG: %s\r\nCONTENT: %s\r\n\r\n", $matches['tag'][$_], $matches['content'][$_]);
  }
```

produces:

```
TAG: Title
CONTENT: Test

TAG: Author
CONTENT: zad0xsis

TAG: Date
CONTENT: July 13th, 2011

TAG: Body
CONTENT: This is a test post and this can continue until the file end
```

*Thought I'd use named tags just for GPs. **Also, if need-be, you can replace the `(?<tag>\w+)` with something more vague such as `(?<tag>.*?)` if there could be spaces, numbers, etc.***

Comment: I like this solution. When I get home I'll be testing every solution and I'll choose the solution that adapts better for me, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$tagValue = array();
$file = fopen("welcome.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file))
{
  $line = fgets($file);
  $tagDelimiter = strpos ($line ,":");
  $tag = substr($line,0,$tagDelimiter);
  $value = substr($line,$tagDelimiter+1,strlen($line)-$tagDelimiter);
  $tagValue[$tag] = $value;
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

You can access your data : `$tagValue["Title"]`

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = file("file.txt");
foreach($file as $line)
{
    preg_match("|(.*?): (.*?)|", $line, $match);
    $tag = $match[1];
    $content = $match[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$file = file('file.txt');

foreach($file as $line)
{
    if(preg_match('/(.*) : (.*)/iUs', $line, $match)
    {
         $tag = $match[1];
         $value = $match[2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use regular expressions? Isn't it easier to use strpos()?

Comment: it is yes... but im more comfortable with preg_match(). it uses the same resources as it would to use strstr and strpos combined. I understand i can do strpos, and then preg_match(), but why use 2 methods instead of 1? Unless some lines arent going to have that match, then use strpos()